# How to retrieve mysql row column data into array loop using wpdb

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm not sure if the database query should be within a `foreach` or if that can be created in the blade view...

```
public function tidestations() {
    global $wpdb;

    $tidedb = new $wpdb('ex_user', 'example_dbpassword', 'schema', 'localhost');

    $ta = array();

    foreach ($tidedb->get_results("SELECT id, stations FROM conditions") as $ti) {

        $ta[] = $ti();

    }

    return $ta;
}
```

In the `conditions` table there are 3 columns: id, stations, waterlevel

Result:

```
Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
```

Comment: Your code looks very strange. Starting with the most obvoius: What does $wpdb contain? Global is bad design btw...

Comment: global $wpdb is the method to instantiate the ability to query a database. This was the method I was taught to connect to the databse in the next line of code.

Comment: that does not help you... I'm strongly assuming you're just doing it wrong. IF $wpdb already contains an object, then `new $wpdb` will produce an error.
Turn up your error reporting, I bet you will see alot of errors and warnings...

Comment: There are no other errors being reported other than the one specified above. All other functions are working as they should without issue. This question is related to the query syntax.

Comment: That query doesn't look overly complicated or wrong to me, but I don't know your database. I suggest you ask the database for the error.

Comment: That's the weird thing here, as the DB queries properly and outputs expected results. The mystery is why the foreach statement is spitting an error.

Answer (score 0):

Changed pass. Face palm. Ex cite. Much oof.

Below is how you can iterate through columns in an external schema table from the same db host as your wp.

```
public function tidestations() {
    global $wpdb;

    $tidedb = new $wpdb('root', 'devpw', 'exdb', 'localhost');

    $ttable = $tidedb->get_results("SELECT * FROM conditions", ARRAY_A);

    $tstations = array();

    foreach($tidedb->get_results("SELECT * FROM conditions") as $key => $row) {
        $station = $row->station;

        $tstations[] = $row->station;
    }

    return $tstations;

}
```